# Train from Verona to Bolzano with bicycles (4 people)

Tags: trains, italy, verona

we're planning a minimal-gear four-day bicycle tour (sleeping in airbnbs and hotels/bookings on the way) from Bolzano through Stelvio and Mortirolo in June (leaving our car in Bolzano) and then plan to return to Bolzano by train on the fourth day.

What are the restrictions / prerequisites on traveling by train with bicycles from Verona to Bolzano?

1. Is there anything I should be aware of?
2. Is it better to buy a ticket in advance or should I buy it when we arrive?
3. Where to buy a ticket from? Is it possible to buy a bicycle ticket in advance?

I have searched and the sites I found did not allow me to specify bike as my luggage during the process of booking the travel.